# Best way to chain a JavaScript function between different files

Tags: javascript, function, object

What's the best way to chain a JavaScript function between different files? In this case, `BusinessObjectCategories()` and `BusinessAddSiteStatusFunctionalities()` are undefined because the function is in another page. Should I get the global object in JavaScript?

```
**Doo.js**
var Doo = new DooObject();



**Doo.Business.js**
function BusinessObject() {}

if (typeof Doo != undefined) {
    Doo.Business = new BusinessObject();
    BusinessObjectCategories();
}



**Doo.Business.Categories.js**
function BusinessObjectCategories() {}

if (typeof Doo != undefined) {
    Doo.Business.Categories = new BusinessObjectCategories();
    BusinessAddSiteStatusFunctionalities();
}



**Doo.Business.Categories.SiteStatus.js**
function BusinessAddSiteStatusFunctionalities() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just example code, it's about how you want to structure your project. You can easily split up all of your functions into different files and `export` them (MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Then, in the file(s) of your choosing, just use `import` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

This is extremely common, and allows you to not pollute up your global scope. Just as easily, you could put a variety of helper functions in a file, and `import` specific functions of need into particular files. This way, you're not split between so many different files and you're still not polluting your global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to go through countless hoops, hard to read code and many headaches... You'll want to use a javascript framework like [Angular](https://angular.io/) in order to apply object oriented concepts to javascript without having to write ugly things like:

```
MyParentFunction.call(this);
```

Javascript frameworks like Angular allows you to use inheritance as you would in most object oriented languages.

```
class MyChildrenClass implements MyParentClass { }
```

If you absolutely want to do it using vanilla javascript, give [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance) a read.